# UIPageView Implementation black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I am new to using `UIPageViewController` and could not find a good explanation for it in `Objective-C`. I tried implementing one on my own, but it only shows a black screen on launch. What am I doing wrong?

I have a ViewController set up in IB which is the initial ViewController, and two others which have the two storyboard IDs below and are just sitting there, without being connected to anything.

Here is my code for the initial ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    UIViewController *vc1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc1"];
    UIViewController *vc2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc2"];

    viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:vc1,vc2, nil];

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[vc1] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return viewControllers[index];
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
     viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

    --currentIndex;
    currentIndex = currentIndex % (viewControllers.count);
    return [viewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
      viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

    ++currentIndex;
    currentIndex = currentIndex % (viewControllers.count);
    return [viewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
}

-(NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return viewControllers.count;
}

-(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can check this out - https://github.com/mindsnacks/MSPageViewController  maybe that will help.

Comment: I can't see the point where you have added your pageViewController to the screen

Comment: It's here: [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];

Comment: @BalázsVincze you've just added page view controller as child view controller, you'll have to do like this `[self.view addSubview: self.pageViewController.view];`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

> addSubview

And after that, you should call

> didMoveToParentViewController

for getting life cycle events on child view controller.

```
@interface ViewController ()<UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPageViewController* pageViewController;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *viewControllers;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    UIViewController *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    self.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:vc1,vc2, nil];

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[vc1] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return self.viewControllers[index];
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
     viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

    --currentIndex;
    currentIndex = currentIndex % (self.viewControllers.count);
    return [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
      viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

    ++currentIndex;
    currentIndex = currentIndex % (self.viewControllers.count);
    return [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
}

-(NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return self.viewControllers.count;
}

-(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}
@end
```

Comment: @Balázs Vincze did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    self.pageController.dataSource = self;
    self.pageController.delegate = self;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(loadNextController)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];


    [[self.pageController view] setFrame:[[self sliderView] bounds]];

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 5;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;

    PageChildVC *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];

    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
    [[self sliderView] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}


- (PageChildVC *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if ((5 == 0) || (index >= 5)) {
        return nil;
    }
     PageChildVC *childViewController = [[PageChildVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"PageChildVC" bundle:nil];
    childViewController.index = index;
    return childViewController;

}
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSUInteger index = ((PageChildVC*) viewController).index;
    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        index = 5;
    }
    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
  }
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSUInteger index = ((PageChildVC*) viewController).index;
    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }
    index++;
    if (index == 5) {
        index = 0;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
     }
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    return 5;
}
- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    return [(PageChildVC *)[self.pageController.viewControllers firstObject] index];
}
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{
    PageChildVC *currentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers[0];
    currentIndex = (int)currentViewController.index;
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:currentIndex];
}
- (void)loadNextController {
    currentIndex++;
    PageChildVC *nextViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:currentIndex];
    if (nextViewController == nil) {
        currentIndex = 0;
        nextViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:currentIndex];
    }
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:@[nextViewController] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:currentIndex];
}
```